# Django problema para iniciar sesión con Azure AD

Tags: python, django, azure, backend, auth

tengo una consulta es debido a que no puedo iniciar sesión por medio de Django usando el active directory de Azure, me sale este código de error.

AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy usando esta app que tengo el active directory

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual es el código que estas usando que urls defines?

Comment: estoy usando python, aunque la duda es si en las urls que me pide la app para redireccion debo tener la app en un app services de azure, ya que estoy desarrollando en el localhost y me tira error al ingresar el 127.0.0.1